# $scope.$watch on $location.search() being fired infinitely when using AngularUI Modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui

I am trying to implement the opening of a modal dialog using $uibModal from Angular UI. Previously I used Bootstrap UI, and opening the modal worked fine. Now, since adding $uibModal.open(), the watcher on $location.search fires infinitely when the modal is invoked using $uibModal.open(). This eventually throws the infinite digest loop error.

Additional Information: The watcher is located in the activate() function and is used to handle when a link is clicked from within the modal pop-up and triggers the modal to update with the new information.

Edit: I've just had an idea. Could it be the fact that I am using a function within LinkModalController to open a modal which also itself uses LinkModalController? Perhaps this causes the watcher to activate again. In this case, is there someway to get the modal to use LinkModalController?

Thanks for any help!

My controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    //Create the LinkModalController and bind it to the core app. This makes it always available.
    angular
        .module('app.core')
        .controller('LinkModalController', LinkModalController);

    LinkModalController.$inject = ['$location', '$q', '$rootScope', '$scope', '$uibModal', 'contentpartservice', 'logger'];
    /* @ngInject */

    function LinkModalController($location, $q, $rootScope, $scope, $uibModal, contentpartservice, logger) {
        var vm = this;

        /*--------------Variable Definitions--------------*/
        vm.modalData = {};
        vm.isModalLoading = true;
        vm.selectedTab;
        vm.urlHistory;

        /*--------------Function Definitions--------------*/
        vm.selectTab = selectTab;
        vm.openModal = openModal;

        /*Activate Controller*/
        activate();

        /*--------------Functions--------------*/
        /*Announcement clicks are handled separately because the announcement data contains the full article*/
        function handleAnnouncementClick(data) {
            vm.modalData = data;
            $("#announcementModal").modal();
            return;
        }

        /*Set the active tab for the open modal*/
        function selectTab(tab) {
            vm.selectedTab = tab;
            return;
        }

        /*Clicking an article of any content type should be funneled through this function. Eventually to be merged with handleSearchResultClick*/
        function handleContentTypeClick(data) {
            setUrl(data.id, data.contentType.value);
            return;
        }

        function handleUrlParamsModalLaunch(data) {
            console.log('launching modal');
            /*Ensure modal is not displaying any data*/
            vm.modalData = {};
            vm.selectedTab = null;

            /*Show modal loading screen*/
            vm.isModalLoading = true;
            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'app/modals/contentTypeModalTemplate.html',
                controller: 'LinkModalController as vm',
            });

            /*Call the content service to return the clicked content article*/
            contentpartservice.getContentItem(data.id, data.type).then(function (contentItem) {
                if (contentItem) {
                    vm.isModalLoading = false;
                    vm.modalData = contentItem;
                    return;
                } else {
                    closeModal("#contentPartModal").then(function () {
                        vm.isModalLoading = false;
                        logger.error('An error occurred while fetching content');
                    });
                    return;
                }
            }, function (error) {
                closeModal("#contentPartModal").then(function () {
                    vm.isModalLoading = false;
                    logger.error('An error occurred while fetching content');
                });
                return;
            });
        }

        /*Close a modal and return a promise object - This allows other code to be executed only after the modal closes*/
        function closeModal(modalId) {
            $(modalId).modal('hide');

            var defer = $q.defer();
            defer.resolve();

            return defer.promise;
        }

        //Function to append information to the URL required to retrieve the displayed article
        function setUrl(contentId, contentType) {
            var urlParams = $location.search();

            if (urlParams.q) {
                $location.search({ q: urlParams.q, type: contentType, id: contentId });
            } else {
                $location.search({ type: contentType, id: contentId });
            }

            console.log($location.search());
            return;
        }

        /*Route link click calls to handle different data structures*/
        function openModal(data, context) {
            switch (context) {
                case 'urlParams':
                    handleUrlParamsModalLaunch(data);
                    break;
                case 'announcement':
                    handleAnnouncementClick(data);
                    break;
                case 'contentType':
                    handleContentTypeClick(data);
                    break;
                default:
                    logger.error('An error occurred while fetching content');
            }

            return;
        }

        /*--------------Listeners--------------*/

        /*Catch links click events broadcast from the $rootScope (shell.controller.js)*/
        $rootScope.$on('openModal', function (event, data, context) {
            vm.openModal(data, context);
            return;
        });

        /*--------------Activate Controller--------------*/
        function activate() {
            /*Create a watcher to detect changes to the URL*/
            $scope.$watch(function () { return $location.search() }, function () {
                alert('url changed');
                /*Wait for modals to render*/
                var urlParams = $location.search();

                if (urlParams.type && urlParams.id) {
                    vm.openModal(urlParams, 'urlParams');
                }                    
            }, true);

            /*Handle the inital page load. (Must wait until content is loaded to open modal). This code only runs once.*/
            $rootScope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function () {
                alert('url changed first laod');
                /*Wait for modals to render*/
                var urlParams = $location.search();

                if (urlParams.type && urlParams.id) {
                    vm.openModal(urlParams, 'urlParams');
                }
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

Here is the text being logged as part of the infinite digest loop error. The error message is a massive block of text, so I've pasted it into a Google Doc: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1esqZSMK4_Tiqckm-IjObqTvMGre2Ls-DWrIycvW5CKY/edit?usp=sharing